# Windows Universal Apps C++ vs C#

Tags: c#, android, c++, mobile, visual-studio-2015

**Qual a diferença entre C# e C++ para desenvolver universal apps?**

Vi que nos templates do `Visual Studio 2015` para `C++` existe um grupo `Cross Plataform` com templates de app para android e ios.

- Como funciona isso?
- Como o VC++ consegue compilar para diferentes dispositivos?
- O compilador utilizado é o próprio VC++?

São 4 perguntas na verdade. :)

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, você pode usar o C++/C# para criar aplicação IOS, Android e Windows e usar projeto Shared para compartilhar biblioteca de classe entre as plataformas, é uma solution que constrói vários binários diferentes, um para cada sistema operacional.

Para entender como ele faz isso você tem que compreender como é a compilação, resumidamente você esta transformando um código fortemente abstrato para um código mais próximo da linguagem da maquina, porém esse código objeto gerado é nativamente criado para um sistema operacional. Antigamente o compilador só gerava códigos para o sistema operacional Windows, agora ele consegue criar binários diferentes para Android e IOS também.

Essa última pergunta não achei nada concreto, mas é bem provável que ele esteja utilizando a tecnologia do Xamarin para fazer.

Mais informações: https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cplusplus-mdd-vs.aspx

Comment: Bem, até onde sei, C# para android só é possível através do Xamarin. Minha dúvida é se esses templates c++ para andoid também são baseados em Xamarin.

E em se tratando de universal apps, existe alguma diferença em um app feito com c++ ou c#? Não sei se eu estou correto, mas me parece que um universal app feito em c++ é nativo enquanto um feito em C# não é.

Comment: Ambos são nativos, tanto C++ quanto C#. E essa tecnologia não utiliza Universal App, o Universal App é uma tecnologia que a Microsoft criou para desenvolvimento entre plataforma Windows Desktop e Windows Phone e serve, principalmente, para ser utilizada na Windows Store, o que pode causar confusão é que, tanto UWP quanto essa nova tecnologia, possui um padrão de arquitetura parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Na Xamarim University você obtém estas respostas. Para gerar código para IOS é utilizado o Xcode e para o Android o Android Studio. O VS gera os binários automaticamente para cada ambiente, utilizando o compilador da plataforma. A linguagem escolhida pode ser c++ ou c#, entretanto você obterá somente acesso a controles usuais. Qualquer biblioteca específica, precisará ser criada em um código especifico do SO.